# Set label value to that of a property of a given object that is bound to a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

So I have a `ListBox` that is bound to a list of student objects through...

```
listBox_studentListBox.ItemsSource = studentList;
```

I have a button that will save data to the list.

```
private void btn_studentListBox_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      currentID = getStudentID();//getStudentID() just finds an available student ID, used to recycle ids of deleted student
      studentList.Add(new cls_student() { studentName = txtBox_studentInfoName.Text, studentID = currentID });
      listBox_studentListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "studentName";
      listBox_studentListBox.SelectedValue = "studentID";
      listBox_studentListBox.Items.Refresh();
}
```

I now when I click on a given item in the `ListBox` I want to load it's data. I am trying to do that here.

```
private void listBox_studentListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     //Load data into labels
}
```

My student object is here.

```
public class cls_student
{
    public string studentName { get; set; }
    public int studentID { get; set; }

    public List<cls_assignment> assignmentList = new List<cls_assignment>();
}
```

As you can see I have another list stored inside the student object, but we will worry about loading that list into a different `ListBox` later.

My concern is how do I access a specific student object based on my selection (just physically left clicking an object in the `ListBox` calling the `SelectionChanged` event handler) to be able to display that data in labels for the user.

I understand that by setting the `DisplayMemberPath` in my Add event handler I can choose what the `ListBox` displays each binded student object as. The issue is that I am not how to bind some sort of value to that object in the `ListBox`. My idea is if I can bind a value to that object then I can be able to access the exact student object I want when I select it to then load it's data into labels.

Any and all feedback is appreciated - this is a updated post of recent post that was asked to be taken down due to my adding objects to a ListBox's .Items property rather than binding it with `ItemsSource`.

**EDIT:** Thanks to a reply I see that if I do `SelectedItem` I can get to the object. I now have this code.

```
private void listBox_studentListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
      testlabel.Content = "SelectedIndex: " + listBox_studentListBox.SelectedIndex;
      cls_student selectedStudent = (cls_student)listBox_studentListBox.SelectedItem;
      lbl_studentInfoName.Content = selectedStudent.studentName;
}
```

My question is if selectedStudent's scope is only during the event handler or if it lasts past it? For context I am used to C++ where I have to delete EVERYTHING or else I get memory leaks. Newer to C# I am.

Comment: listBox_studentListBox.SelectedItem?

Comment: I tried that, and it gave me a hint. It set the label to the object rather than a property of. I realized that if I cast that selected object as a cls_student then I can get it to it. My question is if the selectedStudent is only available within the scope of the event handler? (see question EDIT for details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Binding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx):

```
<ListBox Name="listBox_studentListBox">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <WrapPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding studentName}" />
             </WrapPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And for `Label`:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=listBox_studentListBox, Path=SelectedItem.studentID}" />
```

And in the code behind:

```
currentID = getStudentID();
studentList.Add(new cls_student() { studentName = txtBox_studentInfoName.Text, studentID = currentID });
listBox_studentListBox.ItemsSource = studentList;
```

Comment: After looking at your answer and understanding and implementing it I can't believe I haven't just used binding before. It feels just like binding in angular. :) Thanks for the details response my good friend!

Comment: @JakeMcBride ... You're Welcome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Put a Student property on your view model.  Raise PropertyChanged when it changes.

Bind the SelectedItem of your listbox to Student property.